# Block images from particular domain in GeckoView android

Tags: java, android, geckoview

How can i block image loading from specific domain  in [GeckoView](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/)?
I tried searching equitant method like `setLoadsImagesAutomatically` from webview in GeckoView but no luck.
I found few links like [this](https://github.com/ckuhl/ImageBlockX) and [this](https://github.com/codingotaku/Kurumi-Everywhere).
Can we block image loading by injecting javaScript in GeckoView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a system WebExtension using [`installBuiltIn`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/WebExtensionController.html#installBuiltIn(java.lang.String)) that uses [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) to block loading images from a given domain, or really any other criteria.

Example:

Create a folder under `/assets/` for your extension, e.g. `/assets/block-images` and add a `manifest.json` and `background.js` files like this:

manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "block-images",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Block images from mozilla.org",
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "block-images@example.com"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://*.mozilla.org/*",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
"use strict";

function listener(details) {
  // blocks all images from twitter.com
  return {cancel: true};
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,
  {urls: ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"], types: ["image"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Then you can install the extension at startup somewhere using `ensureBuiltIn`:

```
  runtime
      .getWebExtensionController()
      .ensureBuiltIn(
          "resource://android/assets/block-images/",
          "block-images@example.com");
```

And after that any page that you load in GeckoView will block images to `mozilla.org` as defined in the `background.js` file.

Comment: Thanks for answer Agi,
Can you share some code example on how to get onBeforeRequest listener in GeckoView android?

Comment: sure, I added an example

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. its working fine.

Comment: Hi Agi, Need your one more help.
How can i update above code to allow only specific domain images loading and block all other.
Thanks in advance